# Force Windows 10 to have a second screen

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

I have an Eurolite Pixel 64 Mesh LED Screen that works like a desktop extended second screen on Windows. I just have to connect the DVI output of my graphic card to the Eurolite sending card :

[image]

My problem is Windows 10 doesn't recognize the sending card like a real screen. I still have only one screen in the resolution control panel.

With my preceding ATI graphic card and Windows 7, i could force  to send ouput signal without screen detection. But with Windows 10 and my basic Intel(R) HD graphics 530, i can't.

- My first idea is to create a c# application or service that emulate a second screen and control pixel by pixel the DVI output signal but I doesn't found any help on the web for this.
- My second idea is to create a [dummy dvi plug](https://www.google.fr/search?q=dummy+dvi+plug&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXqp-Y7YDaAhUMWRQKHa3LA0EQ_AUICygC&biw=1920&bih=900) using a [DVI Y](http://www.bceletronica.com.br/PaginaBCE/Catalogos/CABO%20''%20Y%20''%20DVI-D%201%20M%20x%202%20F.jpg) with 3 resistances on the first plug and the sending card in the second plug. Does anybody has already done this ?

Thanks. If it's not the good exchange site, please tell me where, i'll change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an EDID/DDC Emulator

It will emulate an attached screen, you just put it between your computer and the sender.

[image].